# Shell script "A" runs external program "B", I write A's stdin a msg, B call readline can receive this msg too?

Tags: shell, process

I write a shell script A to run an external program B, I want to write to B's stdin, I found child inherits parents' fds.

When I write a msg to A's stdin,  can B receive this msg too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, B will indeed read from the same `stdin` as A. However, do keep in mind that if both A and B read from it simultaneously, you have no way of controlling which of them gets to read what parts, unless you add explicit synchronization between them.

Also, you cannot normally "just write" to `stdin`, if that's the idea you had. You'd have to make it a pipe somehow, and then write to the write end of that pipe.